# Получение переменной из функции flutter

Tags: json, post, frontend, flutter, dart

Есть функция

```
Signin? pov;
void getInnfo(){
final res = await GetHttp().Signin();
pov = res; 
setState((){})
}
```

в pov попадает json ответ на post запрос.

Как я могу отобразить конкретный value из json, в текстовом виджете, без использования кнопки, то есть

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй записать

```
pov = res["value"]
```

вместо value вставить название ключа в json.
Подробнее можешь изучить [здесь](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)